# Autoit GUI, Variables not being declared on button press

Tags: autoit

I am still in the process of learning how to script my own GUIs. Koda has been a big help, I have been messing around with it, learning little bits at a time. However, I have encountered an error that I can not seem to get around. The current GUI I am working on is a simple tool to change bot settings for a game. This gui should have 5 buttons for difficulty setting, and a list of check boxes for the number of bots.

BUT, when I select a difficulty level, bot number, and hit save I get this error:

```
'Variable used without being declared'
```

The error is occuring on this line (botSAVE button at the end):

```
FileWriteLine($file2, "aiSettings.setMaxNBots " & $botnum)
```

I thought the button functions 'Func numClick()' set this variable, but obviously I have overlooked something. Hopefully it is an easy fix. Does anybody see what might be causing this error?   I have posted this question on autoitcsript forums but they seem to shy away from game automation scripts so I didn't really get much help over there.

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <TabConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
Opt("GUIOnEventMode", 1)
#Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=c:\users\admin\desktop\form1.kxf
$Form1 = GUICreate("BF2 Bot-Tool", 418, 499, 759, 83)
GUISetOnEvent($GUI_EVENT_CLOSE, "Form1Close")
GUISetOnEvent($GUI_EVENT_MINIMIZE, "Form1Minimize")
GUISetOnEvent($GUI_EVENT_MAXIMIZE, "Form1Maximize")
GUISetOnEvent($GUI_EVENT_RESTORE, "Form1Restore")
$Pic1 = GUICtrlCreatePic("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\bflogo.jpg", 0, 0, 417, 233)
$Settings = GUICtrlCreateTab(8, 240, 401, 249)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "SettingsChange")
$Bot = GUICtrlCreateTabItem("Bots")
$botSAVE = GUICtrlCreateButton("Save these changes", 220, 433, 169, 33)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "botSAVEClick")
$botDEFAULT = GUICtrlCreateButton("Restore default settings", 28, 433, 169, 33)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "botDEFAULTClick")
$botskill = GUICtrlCreateGroup(" Bot skill level", 28, 265, 169, 145)
$skill1 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("  RECRUIT", 44, 289, 113, 17)
GUICtrlSetTip(-1, "Easy opposition, a damn turkey shoot")
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "skill1Click")
$skill2 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("  TRAINED", 44, 313, 113, 17)
GUICtrlSetTip(-1, "Default setting, opponents are deadly at close range")
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "skill2Click")
$skill3 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("  HARDENED", 44, 337, 113, 17)
GUICtrlSetTip(-1, "Enemies are a force to be reckoned with")
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "skill3Click")
$skill4 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("  VETERAN", 44, 361, 113, 17)
GUICtrlSetTip(-1, "Enemies are experienced, and dangerous")
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "skill4Click")
$skill5 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("  ELITE", 44, 385, 113, 17)
GUICtrlSetTip(-1, "Crack shot opponents will strategize against you. You will not survive")
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "skill5Click")
GUICtrlCreateGroup("", -99, -99, 1, 1)
$botnumber = GUICtrlCreateGroup(" Number of bots ", 220, 265, 169, 145)
$num1 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("2", 236, 289, 25, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num1Click")
$num2 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("4", 236, 313, 25, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num2Click")
$num3 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("6", 236, 337, 25, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num3Click")
$num4 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("8", 236, 361, 25, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num4Click")
$num5 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("10", 236, 385, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num5Click")
$num6 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("12", 284, 289, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num6Click")
$num7 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("14", 284, 313, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num7Click")
$num8 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("16", 284, 337, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num8Click")
$num9 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("18", 284, 361, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num9Click")
$num10 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("20", 284, 385, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num10Click")
$num11 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("24", 340, 289, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num11Click")
$num12 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("28", 340, 313, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num12Click")
$num13 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("32", 340, 337, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num13Click")
$num14 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("36", 340, 361, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num14Click")
$num15 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("40", 340, 385, 33, 17)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "num15Click")
GUICtrlCreateGroup("", -99, -99, 1, 1)
$Server = GUICtrlCreateTabItem("Server")
$serverDEFAULT = GUICtrlCreateButton("Restore default settings", 28, 433, 169, 33)
$serverSAVE = GUICtrlCreateButton("Save these changes", 220, 433, 169, 33)
GUICtrlCreateTabItem("")
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
Opt("MustDeclareVars",1)
#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd


Func Form1Close()
  If @GUI_WINHANDLE = $Form1 Then
    Exit
  EndIf
EndFunc

Func Form1Maximize()
EndFunc

Func Form1Minimize()
EndFunc

Func Form1Restore()
EndFunc

Func num1Click()
$botnum = "2"
EndFunc

Func num2Click()
   $botnum = "4"
EndFunc

Func num3Click()
   $botnum = "6"
EndFunc

Func num4Click()
   $botnum = "8"
EndFunc

Func num5Click()
   $botnum = "10"
EndFunc

Func num6Click()
   $botnum = "12"
EndFunc

Func num7Click()
   $botnum = "14"
EndFunc

Func num8Click()
   $botnum = "16"
EndFunc

Func num9Click()
   $botnum = "18"
EndFunc

Func num10Click()
   $botnum = "20"
EndFunc

Func num11Click()
   $botnum = "24"
EndFunc

Func num12Click()
   $botnum = "28"
EndFunc

Func num13Click()
   $botnum = "32"
EndFunc

Func num14Click()
   $botnum = "36"
EndFunc

Func num15Click()
   $botnum = "40"
EndFunc

Func SettingsChange()
EndFunc

Func skill1Click()
   $skillset = "0.1"
EndFunc

Func skill2Click()
   $skillset = "0.3"
EndFunc

Func skill3Click()
   $skillset = "0.6"
EndFunc

Func skill4Click()
   $skillset = "0.8"
EndFunc

Func skill5Click()
   $skillset = "1.0"
EndFunc

Func botDEFAULTClick()
EndFunc

Func botSAVEClick()
   Local $file = FileOpen("AIDefault.ai", 1)
If $file = -1 Then
    MsgBox(0, "Protected file", "Please ensure that the file 'AIDefault.ai' is not set to Read Only.")
    exit
    EndIf
FileWriteLine($file, "aiSettings.setNSides 2 ")
FileWriteLine($file, "aiSettings.setAutoSpawnBots 1 ")
FileWriteLine($file, "aiSettings.setMaxNBots 64 ")
FileWriteLine($file, "aiSettings.maxBotsIncludeHumans 1")
FileWriteLine($file, "aiSettings.setBotSkill 0.4  ")
FileWriteLine($file, "run BotNames.ai ")
FileWriteLine($file, "aiSettings.setInformationGridDimension 32")
FileWriteLine($file, "run AIPathFinding.ai")
FileWriteLine($file, "run AIBotChanger.ai ")
FileClose($file)

$file2 = FileOpen("AIBotChanger.ai", 1)
If $file2 = -1 Then
    MsgBox(0, "Protected file", "Please ensure that the file 'AIBotChanger.ai' is not set to Read Only.")
    Exit
EndIf
FileWriteLine($file2, "aiSettings.overrideMenuSettings 1")
FileWriteLine($file2, "aiSettings.setMaxNBots " & $botnum)
FileWriteLine($file2, "aiSettings.setBotSkill " & $skillset)
FileWriteLine($file2, "aiSettings.maxBotsIncludeHumans 0")
FileClose($file2)
EndFunc
```

-If anybody sees what I have done wrong, OR has a link to a topic that covers declaring variables with a button click, Help is always appreciated. The only topics I have found are incredibly vague, or differ slightly from what I am look for.

Comment: Please don't edit your own answers into your question. Instead, post it as a separate answer and mark it (after some time) as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: I have solved my variable issue, it seems the variable in the 'Func numClick()' needs to be set as a global variable. Of course it does. :P

Anyway, i finally solved it by changing this:

```
$botnumber = "2"
$skillset = "0.2"
```

To this:

```
Global $botnumber = "2"   
Global $skillset = "0.2"   
EndFunc
```

Did the same with the rest of the functions and now everything is working.